# Problema menú de navegacion sticky (pegajoso) de usar en wordpress

Tags: wordpress, menú, scroll

Necesito hacer un menú de navegacion sticky (pegajoso) para usarlo en el header de mi tema wordpress. El menú tiene que desaparecer cuando bajes el scroll del raton y aparecer al subir.
El problema es que cualquier imagen de mis paginas bajando o subiendo el scroll se sobreponen por encima y no se quedan por abajo.

La estructura de el archivo header.php es la siguiente:

```
<div class="wrapper">
         <header>
            <nav>
               <div class="menu-icon">
                  <i class="fa fa-bars fa-2x"></i>
               </div>
               <div class="logo">
                  LOGO
               </div>
               <div class="menu">
                  <ul>
                     <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                     <li><a href="#">página1</a></li>
                     <li><a href="#">página2</a></li>
                     <li><a href="#">página3</a></li>
                     <li><a href="#">página4</a></li>
                  </ul>
               </div>
            </nav>
         </header>
```

Código Jquery:

```
(function( $ ) {
 $(document).ready(function() {
            $(".menu-icon").on("click", function() {
                  $("nav ul").toggleClass("showing");
            });
      });

      // Scrolling Effect

      $(window).on("scroll", function() {
            if($(window).scrollTop()) {
                  $('nav').addClass('black');
            }

            else {
                  $('nav').removeClass('black');
            }
      })

})( jQuery );
```

alguien tiene alguna sugerencia?

Answer (score 0):

Podrías intentar con lo que dice Gabriel, añádele un `z-index` al menú sticky mayor que el que poseen los elementos que se sobreponen a él. Podrías intentar con algo como:

```
.menu {
  z-index: 100;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Checa/asigna la propiedad z-index de los elementos, para que aparezca al frente el que deseas